# Using Autodesk as an external authentication provider

Tags: oauth, autodesk-forge

I am all around new to working with .net Core, API's, and external provider authentication.

I am helping to build an app that works off the Autodesk Forge API's.

We want to enable users to sign in using OAuth 2.0 with credentials from external authentication providers. Providers like Google and Facebook have an API that allow developers to set this up quite easily but we can't seem to find a solution to doing the same with Autodesk credentials.

We have downloaded the AspNet.Security.OAuth.Autodesk nuget and attempted on setting up Autodesk as we did Google:

```
 services.AddAuthentication()
                .AddAutodesk(autodeskOptions =>
                {
                    autodeskOptions.ClientId = "<our forge app client id>";
                    autodeskOptions.ClientSecret = "<our forge app client secret>";
                })
               .AddGoogle(options =>
                {
                    options.ClientId = "<our google id";
                    options.ClientSecret = "<our google secret>";
                });
```

The rest of the code needed for external logins is set up generically so that it can be applied to any/all providers. We've been successful in setting up external logins for quite a few providers but when we try the same method for Autodesk it sends us to a "invalid redirect-uri".

Is it simply not possible to set up an Oauth 2.0 external login option through Autodesk? Or might we be doing something wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Tara, look into [folowing](https://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/tutorials/viewhubmodels) this tutorial provided by autodesk, it will guide you through quite nicely

Comment: What was the error you ran into? Looking at the [code](https://github.com/aspnet-contrib/AspNet.Security.OAuth.Providers/commit/4d5a766b06e4b3a7c02c42ebdf2a164439ea0fec) of this provider it appears to be implemented correctly - will give this a go myself soon

Answer (score 0):

During App registration in Autodesk Platform Services you must configure your callback url, something like `https://your-awesome-app.com/signin-autodesk`.
See https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/oauth/v2/tutorials/create-app/#step-2-register-an-app for details. You can find the Callback path in the [AspNet.Security.OAuth.Providers repo](https://github.com/aspnet-contrib/AspNet.Security.OAuth.Providers/blob/afe2a77cede80b864786df9be6eb568b02e24551/src/AspNet.Security.OAuth.Autodesk/AutodeskAuthenticationDefaults.cs#L32)